# Why does this method signature work?

Tags: ios, methods, method-signature

I just ran across a bit of code that has a method like this:

```
- (void) AddImage:(NSString *)imageURL: (UIImage *)image{
    [imgCache setObject:image forKey:imageURL];
}
```

Normally I see methods that say:

```
-(typeReturned)methodParameter1:(Param1Type)name1 Parameter2:(Param2Type)name2{
    //do something
}
```

But this method seems to have omitted the Parameter2.  Why does this work?

Answer (score 4):

This is at least uncommon and throws a warning. "imageURL" is not "Parameter2" but "name1". So "Parameter2" is empty. You would call it this way:

```
[self AddImage:@"eins" :[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
```

I would avoid it :).

Comment: I dont understand.  What do you mean imageURL is name1?

Comment: The name of the first method is `AddImage::`. `imageURL` and `image` are not part of the method name, they are the arbitrary placeholder names for the arguments.

Comment: yes i understand they are arguments, but what im saying is, normally each argument passed in has a type defined and a small prefix like: withImage:forURL: etc...this method has one of those prefixes for the imageURL but not for the image.

Comment: @marciokoko You are right, but only in the sense of convention. It is conventional to name methods `-(void)doSomeThingObj1:(id)obj1 andObj2:(id)obj2`. But as far as the compiler and runtimes are concerned, `AddImage::` is perfectly legal.

Comment: Cool!  Ok so you can omit everything except the first prefix...like = -(void)methodNameWithSomeObject:(type)name1 :(type)name2 :(type)name3...